# Do the water filters in Pure & Clear filters work?

Tags: consumer-products, chemistry, chlorine

Dr Mercola advertises [Pure & Clear Filters](http://waterfilters.mercola.com/drinking-water-filter.aspx):

> Pure & Clear filters use a “selective filtration” process rather than a mechanical one for a couple of very important reasons. This advanced technology helps remove harmful contaminants such as THMs and lead, but retains beneficial minerals including potassium and calcium.  The contaminants or other substances removed or reduced by this water treatment device are not necessarily present in your water.

[…]

> The exclusive five stage dual cartridge system removes contaminants based on their level of prevalence, eliminating the most competitive compounds first, such as chlorine and sediment, and allowing the latter stages to focus on the more difficult task of removing lead and synthetic chemicals.

[…]

> Lead is reduced by a complex ion-exchange process that replaces harmful lead ions with healthy potassium ions.

[…]

> Herbicides, pesticides, industrial solvents and other synthetic chemicals are removed through absorption.

Do these water filters work?

Comment: This page is filled with nonsense - e.g. the best and purest water comes from mountain streams. ([Not a safe assumption!](http://survivaltopics.com/that-water-is-unsafe-to-drink/)) That doesn't necessarily mean these filters don't do their job.